# NFS hide /export from path

Tags: nfs, export

How can I share FolderA on ServerA so that my client can simply access it as ServerA:/FolderA if FolderA is not in / ?

Lets say FolderA is actually

```
/usr/local/test/RandomName
```

I can use bind in fstab to shorten it and put it in /export

```
/usr/local/test/RandomName /export/FolderA none bind 0 0
```

So now, I can mount it as

```
mount -t nfs ServerA:/export/FolderA /media/folderA
```

What I really want is

```
mount -t nfs ServerA:/FolderA /media/folderA
```

The server is Ubuntu 10.04 and the clients will include Macs and Linux machines

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the base directory in your NFS exports. To do that and make `/export` the base directory you should open the file

```
/etc/exports
```

and enter the following in the first line:

```
/export  the.IP.of.THEclientsyouwant(ro,fsid=0)
```

With the option fsid=0 (or fsid=root) set you won't call the full path on the client side and then the command

```
mount -t nfs ServerA:/FolderA /media/folderA
```

just will work as you will.

[exports(5) Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports)
[/etc/exports configuration - Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that using bind in your server's fstab. but I do know you can do this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/test/RandomName /FolderA
```

Configure your /etc/exports file to export /FolderA and you should be good.

Comment: I'd prefer not to clutter up my root / folder if possible

Comment: Pretty sure that's the only way to do it though. Else, I think you're stuck with /exports/FolderA or /nfs/FolderA

Answer (score 0):

*The sole `fsid=0` didn't work for me.*

`nfs-utils`>=2.4.1 got [`Add the "[exports] rootdir" option to nfs.conf`](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-nfs/cover/20190528203122.11401-1-trond.myklebust@hammerspace.com/) feature (May 28, 2019):

> The following patchset adds support for the "rootdir" configuration
> option for nfsd in the "[exports]" section in /etc/nfs.conf.
>
> If a user sets this option to a valid directory path, then nfsd will
> act as if it is confined to a chroot jail based on that directory. All
> paths in /etc/exports and the exportfs utility are then resolved
> relative to that directory.

**Something like this should work:**

*Note: I couldn't make exporting `/` root path work but exporting through a subdirectory did it.*

Target dir bound to `/export/nfs/FolderA`.

`/etc/nfs.conf`:

```
[exports]
rootdir=/export
```

`/etc/exports`:

```
/nfs (fsid=0) # workaround for `/` path
/nfs/FolderA
```

Access it `nfs://server_name/nfs/FolderA`

Answer (score -3):

Open following file on NFS server:

```
/etc/exports
```

and enter following details to it:

```
/usr/local/test/RandomName XX.XX.XX.XX(rw)
```

Then login NFS client and do mount as follows:

```
mount -t nfs YY.YY.YY.YY:/usr/local/test/RandomName /media/folderA
```

**Fstab entry:**

```
YY.YY.YY.YY:/usr/local/test/RandomName /media/folderA nfs defaults 0 0
```

**Note:**

```
XX.XX.XX.XX - IP of NFS client
YY.YY.YY.YY - IP of NFS server
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question at all